# Do I need a spare slot to replace a drive in an LVM raid array?

Tags: lvm, raid5

I am planning to set up an LVM raid 5 array and looked at how to replace a faulty drive.
I found the `replace` command
`lvconvert --replace dev_to_remove vg/lv [possible_replacements]`

For this to work, do I need to insert the new drive first in a differnent slot?
What do I do if i just want t swap the drive in the same slot?
Will LVM see the new drive and don't recognise it as an existing physical volume and then allow me to make a new pysical volume and then can  I just use the replace command and specify the same device path again?
Thanks

Comment: well in general it's always better to have a additional slot free in case of emergency. in fact it could be happen that a other drive will failure due the heavy restore time

Comment: Which operating system and version, Linux?  Presumably because I don't know of another with lvconvert, but you should tag your question with your environment.